# Batch Dictionary

Tags: batch-file, dictionary, cmd

**Hello everyone!** Basically, I want to make a batch program that searches for a word in a file, then it would write me back the word if it's found, and finally it would write me the second part of it in another line.

The file.abc is formatted like this:

```
man,viro
woman,virino
```

Here's what I mean:

```
@echo off


set /p text=
findstr /i "%text%" file.abc


if %errorlevel%==0 (
for /f "delims=, tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /i "%text%" file.abc') do (
set translation=%%a
goto translation
)
)


if %errorlevel%==1 (
echo Nothing found!
goto done
)


:translation
echo.
echo %translation%


:done
pause >nul


rem and it usually finds the word correctly and even echoes me the second token
rem but my problem is that it writes out the whole text (both tokens)
```

If I type in a word, for example `man` it gives me the output `man` `man,viro` then `viro` but I only want `man` to be seen and `viro`.

So, I would be glad if someone could help me with this, I'm not so experienced with batch files yet :(

Comment: You did not ask a question. You only stated what you want to implement, but not what your current issue is.

Comment: There's no question in that sentence either. You just said exactly what you said above.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call findstr, you can redirect the output to nul:

```
findstr /i "%text%" file.abc > nul
```

Comment: works also fine on Win8.1. Although I suggest `findstr /i /b "%text%,"` (`/b`to start at the beginning of the line and inclusive the comma), so neither `woman` nor `manicor` nor `amanda` would be found when searching for `man`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with several problems:

1. `findstr /i "%text%" file.abc` in the 5th line... this emits "man,viro" ... not sure if you want this except for debugging purpose - remove it.
2. `tokens=2` in line 9. finds only the word right of the comma. Change it to `tokens=1,2`
3. `set translation=%%a` in line 10. because of 2. change it to `=%%b` to accept the second token found
4. Add the following command at line 10: `@echo %%a`
5. You'll find text you do not want to find and this is your MAIN PROBLEM here. You'll find 'man' in 'woman', You'll find 'man' if it was part of the word on the right side of the comma. Make use of regular expressions, change the findstr-parameters as follows: `findstr /i /r "^%text%,[a-z]*"`

   ```
   echo off


   set /p text=
   REM findstr /i "%text%" file.abc

   if %errorlevel%==0 (
   for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%a in ('findstr /i /r "^%text%,[a-z]*" file.abc') do (
   echo %%a
   set translation=%%b
   goto translation
   )
   )


   if %errorlevel%==1 (
   echo Nothing found!
   goto done
   )


   :translation
   echo.
   echo %translation%


   :done
   pause >nul
   ```

Comment: That would be too much for here but if you type for /? at the command propmt you'll get a comprehensive help message including the /F parameter